# SoapUI handshake_failure on https endpoint service

Tags: soapui

When the project endpoint moves to https from http, I got handsshake_failure error for the request. By checking some topics, I modified SoapUI-5.2.1.vmoptions file by adding this

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2

or with SSL. And restart SoapUI.

But I still get the error.

Answer (score 7):

This is a handshake problem, that means SoapUI doesn't understand the encrypted SSL/TLS content due to lack of certificate. To fix that, you simply need to import the certificate into your soapui's keystore. The keystore file name is "cacert" and it's usually located at sosoapui_home/jre/lob/security but you might want to have your own by pointing it directly from Preferences/SSL settings as shown in the screenshot.

You can find the **instruction** of importing the key in my [blog](http://hardwayoreasyway.blogspot.com/search?q=soapui%20ssl)

[image]

Comment: nice blog! I found the _cacerts_ file as you said, I imported my self signed certificates, but nothing changed, unfortunately.  I still get _SSLHandshakeExption: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure_ (btw. the password for the keystore is `changeit`, same as the JDK trust store.)

Comment: Same here it didn't work, I made sure the cert was added with this command "keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts"

Comment: do you know how to activate ssl debug mode in soapui? thanks

Comment: @DiegoRamos I'm not sure about Mac, but if you use Windows, you can see more details and logs if you go to the `/bin` folder that SoapUI is installed and run the `soapui.bat` file. Then you will see the terminal window with background logs.

if you want more details, open the `soapui.bat`, find the line starting with `set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m ...` and add `-verbose`. like this: `JAVA_OPTS=-verbose -Xms128m ..`.

Answer (score 5):

moved to soap ui 5.4 solved this problem for me

Comment: I had the same issue after setting up my keystore on soap ui, after moving to 5.4 it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by adding this line:

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
to the file [soaphome]\bin\soap.vmoptions
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'd put the same setting above into the .bat file in the same directory, which wasn't working.  This worked!

Comment: Had to add to to soapui.bat

Answer (score 1):

SoapUI has subfolder `jre`, where is its java. Java 7 was here, I replaced it with Java 8, and it solved the issue.

It is not the first time when we observed ssl problems in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

I did try the accepted answer but it didn't work in my case.

To make it work :

1. I had to add the JCE unlimited strengh policy JARs (they come in two
   flavors JKD8 or JDK7 so get the right one for your case) I did put them in the security folder of SoapUI.
2. Next I had to specify : 
   -Dsoapui.https.ciphers=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 in my SoapUI config file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Latest version of SOAPUI. Issue will get resolved

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem with SoapUI 5.7.0.
But it was nothing from above.

**What have we done?:**

We've created an KeyStore with KeyStore Explorer while importing Key and Cert in PEM-Format.
But using this Keystore in SoapUI results in handshake failure in SoapUI.

**What was the solution:**

We used command line tools `openssl` and `keytool`

Create PKCS12 KeyStore:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in <path to .pem cert> -inkey <path to .key cert> -out <desired name of the .p12 file with the extension> -name <cert alias>`

Import PKCS12 into Java keystore:

`keytool -importkeystore -v -srckeystore <path to .p12 file> -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore <path to .jks> -deststoretype JKS`

If you have already the PKCS12 file it is also possible to use it directly in SoapUI.
It is also possible to convert the PKCS12 file with KeyStore Explorer to JKS.